# Parameters Process Failed when I select a

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jboss7.x

Hi I am doing something really simple but it is not working I am using jboss and jsf 2.0.
So I am trying to create a form that shows some fields according to a selection from the user of dropdown menu so I am using selectOneMenu

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="formTaxon">
                <h:outputLabel value="Nombre Científico Taxón" for="taxonInput" />
                <p:inputText value="#{taxonDM.taxon.nombreCientificoTaxon}"
                    id="taxonInput" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Nombre Común" for="nombreComunInput" />
                <p:inputText value="#{taxonDM.taxon.nombreComunTaxon}"
                    id="nombreComunInput" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Tipo" for="tipoTaxon" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoTaxon" value="#{taxonDM.taxon.tipoTaxon}"
                    name="tipoTaxon">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione uno" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{tipoTaxonDM.tiposTaxones}" var="txn"
                        itemValue="#{txn.idTipoTaxon}" itemLabel="#{txn.nombreTipo}" />
                    <f:ajax process="@this"
                        listener="#{taxonController.tipoTaxonesXX}" render="formTaxon" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:inputText id="test" val="" />
            </h:panelGrid>
```

I also tried without the listener first

But nothing works, I dont get any errors on the server I get an error when I check the scripts with firebug

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><error><error-name>class java.lang.IllegalStateException</error-name><error-message><![CDATA[Parameters processing failed.]]></error-message></error></partial-response>
```

I tested it on a jboss 7.0.2 and 7.1.1 with firefox.  I read there was a bug between IE and jboss 7.1.1 related with this but I guess this is not the case.

I also tried with h:selectOneMenu instead of p:selectOneMenu.  There was no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the value of your dropdown box as a `taxon.tipoTaxon` in `<p:selectOneMenu id="tipoTaxon" value="#{taxonDM.taxon.tipoTaxon}">`, when the item values are `idTipoTaxon`.

As far as we can get, the former is of type `TipoTaxon` and the latter is of type `Integer`, most probably. So when JSF tries to convert between those types it fails.

You need either to provide for a [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) so that JSF would know how to convert submitted strings to your model objects (you can find many examples here, on Stack Overflow), or bind dropdown value as an integer as well like `value="#{taxonDM.taxon.idTipoTaxon}"`.

Comment: Yeah I am so dumb, it makes more sense, i have never bind a value before I ll guess have to read more.

Comment: You're welcome. Reading and self-trying is definitely the key to success.